# MacOS Default Sharing Settings

Tags: macos, settings

I have a question regarding default macOS settings, how they are if the MacBook is newly set up after buying or factory reset on macOS Ventura and Sonoma?

I need to know the default settings for the sharing section: **System Preferences** > **General** > **Sharing**. There are different sections like Bluetooth Sharing, Remote Login, Screen Sharing, and others.

What are the default states (On or Off) here for each of them after a fresh normal MacBook setup?

Comment: I think it defaults to all sharing off.

Comment: Yes. You don't share anything unless you explicitly turn it on.

Comment: Thanks very much! Sometimes I actually think the Apple Support is just giving random answers. One told me its all off except bluetooth and caching but he told me he is not really sure and he seemed not that competent...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've bought a new Mac in July 2023 and haven't changed the Sharing settings. Here is the default set:

[image: Default set of options]

Comment: You are my hero! Thank you very much :)